# Websphere not directing request to proxy server on response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, websphere, reverse-proxy

I have secured apache reverse proxy configured in front of my websphere 8 application server. I have set generic JVM arguments -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort but the requests on response.sendRedirect are not directed to peoxy server. It is directed to defualt port 9080. 
How to solve this issue ?
I have solved this issue on Tomcat & Jboss by modifying my connector port as follows

connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" socket-binding="http" scheme="https"  proxy-name=" 192.168.1.1 " proxy-port="443" secure="true"

How do I solve this for Websphere ?

Comment: AFAIK, the parameters you mention:  -Dhttps.proxyHost and -Dhttps.proxyPort are used to stablish the "forward" proxy of your organisation and have nothing to do with the reverse proxy configured in Apache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our case, with Liberty being behind Integrated Web Services for IBM i (IWS) and running on a different port, we did not have an option to add

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort -true
trusthostheaderport - true
```

Our only option, based on [Open Liberty documentation](https://openliberty.io/docs/latest/forwarded-header.html#_forwarded_and_x_forwarded_headers_and_verification), was to add following headers at the reverse proxy

```
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
```

As well as setting it to preserve the host in `X-Forwarded-Host` header. This is achieved using `ProxyPreserveHost On` on Apache mod-proxy, but others might do it by default.

Apache mod proxy configuration

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved this problem by following below steps.

1. Add following in Apache web server's virtual host tag . What you actually need is to forward along the protocol that was used to access the server.

   VirtualHost *:443>
   RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https" 
    ….
   /VirtualHost>

For more explanation refer site 
https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2012/08/08/setting-up-apache-as-a-ssl-front-end-for-play/

2. Following properties needs be added in Websphere webcontainer properties through admin console.
   Go to Application servers > server1 > Web container > Custom properties
   Add Following properties

httpsIndicatorHeader - 
X-Forwarded-Proto   (Request header value set in web server (in our case it is https) )

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extractHostHeaderPort - 
true    (To obey request port no)

trusthostheaderport -
true    (To obey request port no)

Refered the below site for this settings

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21569667

http://129.33.205.81/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using like below

response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() +
        "/my/main.jsp");

Here - request.getContextPath gives the proxied server info.

As a quick fix I resolved it using the proxy server values from properties files.

response.sendRedirect("get proxy server name from prop file" +
        "/my/main.jsp");

Comment: Yes I have tried this solution already and it is working but I want server side settings/configuration for acheving this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In our case (Websphere Liberty 21.0.0.9), we simply added a couple of directives in the corresponding Apache virtual host configuration:

- RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
- ProxyPreserveHost On`

These directives are valid only from Apache 2.3.3 on

Both are mentioned in the [article mentioned below by @Darshan Shah](http://129.33.205.81/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.iseries.doc/ae/rweb_custom_props.html)